# Snippet expansion without pressing Tab or similar completion/expansion/trigger keys

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I have been using Vim with VimTeX and Ultisnips plugins as my LaTeX front end and I would now like to try VSCode and LaTeX-Workshop extension out.

Is the equivalent of the following possible via VSCode snippets?

```
snippet mm "Inline Math" wA
\\( $1 \\) $0
endsnippet
```

This snippet has option `wA` and the functionality here is that if the user types `mm` in any line (the `wA` option stands for the beginning of a new word and the expansion is automatic with no need to press a snippet trigger/expansion/completion (e.g., Tab) key.  Within a line, this provides the `\( | \)` inline math environment.

My initial thought was to have the following in `latex.json` snippets file:

```
"mm": {
        "prefix": "mm",
        "body": [
            "\( $1 \)"
        ],
        "description": "inline math"
}
```

but this needs the snippet expansion/completion/trigger key which is the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key pressed after `mm`

I think this is not possible -- every snippet expansion seems to require the snippet trigger/expansion/completion key. I would like to confirm that it is indeed possible/not possible within VSCode.

The use case is that pressing `mm` is a lot easier since the keys are close to the home row rather than pressing any other snippet trigger/expansion/completion key.

---

ETA: I got confirmation that this is currently not possible in VSCode. See [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/discussions/3615)

20 upvotes on [VSCode Github page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170423) is likely to get work started for eventual completion in several years.

Comment: See if the extension HyperSnips works for you.

Comment: Yes, Hypersnips is quite amazing. Since I made this post, I was guided to the same extension by someone else as well. It is much faster than native VSCode snippets. VSCode should make hypersnips like expansion native and inbuilt out of the box, imo.